# Convert curl command to pycurl

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

im trying to convert the following curl call into pycurl , can someone help me out with that .

```
curl --request 'POST' 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/mutes/users/create.json' --data 'screen_name=fails' 
--header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="mZRm27WsyGa8PRxcDC", oauth_nonce="5d10f384e1a8f176ca0a74b3dd2", oauth_signature="vYY%2BbHfXv1PTfc0MbY9jcLU%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1431346223", oauth_token="17718839-bewY3FfcV7vBPSd3pBOzscoxGmFeU", oauth_version="1.0"'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? It seems to me your workflow is: read [pycurl](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl) API and translate [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) CLI arguments/options. PS: There is almost **never** a "magic" "translate xyz into abc" button!

Comment: Have you tried the [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) library? *HTTP for Humans*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it an option to use [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) in python? It is much easier to use. Here is a small code example (not runnable):

```
 import requests
 import json

 myurl= 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/mutes/users/create.json'
 to_post = {"label":"value"}
 to_post = json.dumps(to_post)  #Convert to json if that is the correct content-type
 r = requests.post(myurl,data = to_post , auth = ('username', 'password'))
```

It is much more complicated in pycurl. Require many more lines.