# Converting cURL to Python Requests error

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to convert the cURL to Python request but doesn't work.

**cURL:** `curl -kv -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'https://IP-address/api/v1/login' -d '{"username":"api", "password":"APIPassword"}'`

My Python requests code:

```
import requests

url = "https://IP-address/api/v1/login"

payload = "'{\"username\":\"api\", \"password\":\"APIPassword\"}'"
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/json",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False)

print(response.text)
```

Which doesn't work and gives me 400 bad requests error.

I tried converting using the https://curl.trillworks.com/

which gives me the following code which doesn't work either.

```
import requests

url = 'https://IP-address/api/v1/login'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"username":"api", "password":"APIPassword"}'

output = requests.get(url, data=data, verify=False)

print (output)
```

Can anyone please help me identify the issue here.

Edit: I have edited 2nd script to produce output: Which gives 500 Error

Comment: What about the flags that you've specified in the cURL command? Why are you not including them in your python script?

Comment: The 400 bad request probably stems from your original `payload` being invalid JSON. Your `curl` command has single quotes (`'`) around the JSON, but those are just so `bash` would interpret the whole thing as a single argument.

Comment: @AakashVerma `-k` is `--insecure`, it is the same as `verify=False`; `-v` is `--verbose`; `-H` is `--header`; `-d` is `--data`

Comment: Your own python code does have mistakes. In your second code, what does "doesn't work either" mean? 400 or 403 or something else?

Comment: @mononoke You're right - the second code snippet doesn't actually print out the response

Comment: Look at the pycurl example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167656/convert-curl-command-to-pycurl)

Comment: @mononoke I have modified the 2nd script to generate output. Which gives 500 error.

Comment: 500 is `Internal Server Error`. This means whatever you're connecting to has run into an unexpected problem and can't continue.

Comment: @Kendas but if I run curl command from terminal, it just gives the expected output. The server is good I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `json` parameter in `requests.post` for json data. It also takes care of the headers.

```
data = {"username":"api", "password":"APIPassword"}
response = requests.post(url, json=data, verify=False)
```

Comment: This appears to be working, I'm getting response as 200. But how do I see the actual output? When I run the curl, I get a session-token as output, but how do I get in Python requests?

Comment: Just print it, ie: `print(response.content)` or if it's a json response use: `print(response.json())`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make sure you're sending valid JSON in your payload would be to use the `json` python library to format your payload via `json.dumps()`, which returns a string representing a json object from an object. This was especially useful to me when I needed to send a nested json object in my payload.

```
import json 
import requests

url = 'https://sample-url.com' 
headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': f'{auth_key}'}
payload =   {   "key": "value",
                "key": ["v1", "v2"],
                "key": {
                         "k": "v"
                        }
                ...
            }

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```